# Symfony return 401 unauthorized instead of 404 and 302

Tags: php, symfony, http-headers

for security perpose i want to return always 401 result instead redirection when user is unauthenticated and instead 404 code when page not found

```
    firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            success_handler: authentication.handler.login_success_handler
        logout: true
        anonymous: true
```

Comment: IMO, this is bad idea. By doing so, you are revealing, to unauthenticated users, that endpoint does exist but users cannot access it. Not because they are unauthorized but unauthenticated - very different...